# Loop through a python dataframe with 10 urls and extract contents from them (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I have a csv called 'df' with 1 column. I have a header and 10 urls.

```
Col
"http://www.cnn.com"
"http://www.fark.com"
etc 
etc
```

This is my ERROR code

```
import bs4 as bs
df_link = pd.read_csv('df.csv')    
for link in df_link:
        x = urllib2.urlopen(link[0])
        new = x.read()
# Code does not even get past here as far as I checked
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(new,"lxml")
        for text in soup.find_all('a',href = True):
            text.append((text.get('href')))
```

I am getting an error which says

```
ValueError: unknown url type: C
```

I also get other variations of this error like

The issue is, it is not even getting past

```
x = urllib2.urlopen(link[0])
```

On the other hand; This is the WORKING CODE...

```
url = "http://www.cnn.com"
x = urllib2.urlopen(url)
new = x.read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(new,"lxml")
for link in soup.find_all('a',href = True):
    links.append((link.get('href')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixed answer

I didn't realize you were using `pandas`, so what I said wasn't very helpful.

The way you want to do this using `pandas` is to iterate over the rows and extract the info from them. The following should work without having to get rid of the header:

```
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd
import urllib2

df_link = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

for link in df_link.iterrows():
    url = link[1]['Col']
    x = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    new = x.read()
    # Code does not even get past here as far as I checked
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(new,"lxml")
    for text in soup.find_all('a',href = True):
        text.append((text.get('href')))
```

#### Original misleading answer below

It looks like the header of your CSV file is not being treated separately, and so in the first iteration through `df_link`, `link[0]` is `"Col"`, which isn't a valid URL.

Comment: So shall i remove the header? or shall I use link[1]. I will try both and update.

Comment: I made an assumption about what you were doing that was wrong... I've updated my answer!

Comment: Thank you.. I will definitely get back to you once I try it:)

Comment: Works :) thank you. I finally switched to requests package for the same!